# Internal server error while importing sql file?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache, wampserver

I am importing an SQL file and it shows me an error like this

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. Please contact the server
>   administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this
>   error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>   More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

I have already make changes in `php.ini` file, which are listed below

```
MAX_UPLAOD_SIZE = 20M
MAX_EXECUTION_TIME = 600
POST_MAX_SIZE = 20M
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Check your server logs.

Comment: `Give me solution as soon as.` -1 to that.

Comment: share the code what u have written.

Comment: I am importing a big sql file in phpmyadmin. Sql file size is more than 40 mb. I set value of max_uplaod_size upto 60mb. but still its not working

Comment: Make sure `POST_MAX_SIZE` is also set accordingly. That, and you are consistently misspelling `MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check your /var/log/apache2/error.log (or what server do you use?) It contains a full error description.
2. Import big SQL files via ssh/mysql client:

   mysql -u username -p dbname < /path/to/sql/file.sql

Comment: I am using Windows not an Unix/Linux system, So that I can't import it via command line. I have seen apache log but I can't find anything in it.

Comment: @GhanshyamKatariya That is very un-true, **Windows has command line too**, only thing you have to find is the mysql executable, then open terminal in that location and this command will work the same :) ...In fact WINDOWS is the one with command line, Linux(es) have terminals :P

Comment: @BaBL86 : If you advice importing big SQL through mysql client, you should also advice, that you might need to set `max_allowed_packet` in the mysql settings to a higher amount and restart mysql.

Answer (score 0):

@BaBL86 Is correct, that is a valid solution on WAMPServer and Windows, you just need to do the following.

Run the MySQL command prompt as follows:

```
left click the WampManager icon -> MySQL -> MySQL Console
```

Enter the password for your 'root' user account or if you have not set one yet just hit enter.

Now enter the following at the Mysql prompt

```
source C:/path/to/your/backup.sql
```

Also if you have really set the parameters in the php.ini like you say you have

```
MAX_UPLAOD_SIZE = 20M
MAX_EXECUTION_TIME = 600
POST_MAX_SIZE = 20M
```

Set them properly

```
upload_max_size = 20M
max_execution_time = 600
post_max_size = 20M
```

But using the MySQL Console you can set them all back to the way you found them as that is not affected by any PHP limitations like phpMyAdmin is.